# .htaccess redirection for SEO configuration

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, seo

I have an angularJs based portfolio, Google crawler offer a URI tool for similar platforms. replaces the `#!` by `?_escaped_fragment_=` which you can use server redirection to changed the directory to serve static files.

I don't use `#!` so the `?_escaped_fragment_=` will be inserted at the end. What I like to do is to make this pattern:

```
www.mywebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=
www.mywebsite.com/page/?_escaped_fragment_=
www.mywebsite.com/page/5?_escaped_fragment_=
```

Redirects to

```
www.mywebsite.com/snapshot
www.mywebsite.com/snapshot/page/
www.mywebsite.com/snapshot/page/5
```

This is the .htaccess file that I used:

```
RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=$
  RewriteRule ^$ /snapshot/
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ -  [L]
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

The problem is that It only works for the base URL (index.html).
Is there a thing that I am missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the escaped fragment like this:

```
http://yourangularwebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/page/5
```

Then redirect it in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=/([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^$ /snapshot/%1 [R,L]
```

This should redirect you to http://yourangularwebsite.com/snapshot/page/5?_escaped_fragment_=/page/5